# Dockerized app with Nginx (via docker-compose) - 502 Bad Gateway Error

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, phoenix-framework

I have a Phoenix app, MyApp, which I am attempting to Dockerize and deploy on Ubuntu 18.04. I have tried to follow some guides to set up Nginx properly, but I either receive a 502 Bad Gateway error or cause too many redirects depending on how I have tried to set up the Nginx reverse-proxy.

The ideal situation is that I can use `docker-compose up` and it will initialize the web app and Nginx. This is my current docker-compose.yml file:

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.5'

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ./data/nginx/app.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - ./data/nginx/error.log:/etc/nginx/error_log.log
      - ./data/nginx/cache/:/etc/nginx/cache
      - /etc/letsencrypt/:/etc/letsencrypt/
    environment:
      - ENV=production
      - APPLICATION_URL=http://myapp.domain
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443

  ...

  web:
    depends_on:
      - nginx
    image: "myapp:0.1.0"
    restart: unless-stopped
    expose:
      - "80"
    env_file:
      - config/docker.env
```

Without including Nginx the same image-version of myapp works with `ports: - 80:4000` as Phoenix is configured to expect traffic on port 4000. The following is my nginx app config specified, I believe, by the volumes in the docker-compose.yml.

**data/nginx/app.conf**

```
events {

}

http {
  client_max_body_size 20m;

  proxy_cache_path /etc/nginx/cache keys_zone=one:500m max_size=1000m;

  server {
      proxy_cache one;
      listen 80;
      listen 443 ssl;
      server_name myapp.domain;

      location / {
          proxy_pass http://localhost:4000;
          rewrite ^/myapp.domain(.*)$ $1 break;
      }

      ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/myapp.domain/fullchain.pem;
      ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/myapp.domain/privkey.pem;
      include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
  }
}
```

I don't know exactly how to set up the ports so that the web traffic is sent properly through Nginx and reverse proxied to myapp. I believed the localhost would work because when I run `docker-compose up` I see `Running MyAppWeb.Endpoint with cowboy 2.6.1 at http://localhost:4000`.

When I do attempt to access the site I see this on my server logs
`[error] 6#6: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 162.158.119.89, server: myapp.domain, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:4000/", host: "myapp.domain"`

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: how about is Phoenix application dockerfile  ?

Comment: @ThanhNguyenVan I don't think it should be related because the application does compile and can be accessed through HTTP when the Nginx implementation is removed after a few config changes. Does including Nginx as a service for docker-compose require a change to my Dockerfile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to link web service on nginx container, docker-compose will look like:

```
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ./data/nginx/app.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - ./data/nginx/error.log:/etc/nginx/error_log.log
      - ./data/nginx/cache/:/etc/nginx/cache
      - /etc/letsencrypt/:/etc/letsencrypt/
    environment:
      - ENV=production
      - APPLICATION_URL=http://myapp.domain
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    links:
      - web

  web:
      depends_on:
        - nginx
      image: "myapp:0.1.0"
      restart: unless-stopped
      expose:
        - "4000"
      env_file:
        - config/docker.env
```

Then update `data/nginx/app.conf`

```
events {

}

http {
  client_max_body_size 20m;

  proxy_cache_path /etc/nginx/cache keys_zone=one:500m max_size=1000m;

  server {
      proxy_cache one;
      listen 80;
      listen 443 ssl;
      server_name myapp.domain;

      location / {
          proxy_pass http://web:4000;
          rewrite ^/myapp.domain(.*)$ $1 break;
      }

      ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/myapp.domain/fullchain.pem;
      ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/myapp.domain/privkey.pem;
      include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for that suggestion! That actually clears up a lot of confusion because I see now how Docker more or less interpolates the service name as the IP I think. The second line in the Nginx config should also read `rewrite ^/web(.*)$ $1 break;` then? Now I'm getting a 521 error and my Phoenix app is saying that it `Could not check origin for Phoenix.Socket transport` and `Origin of the request: https://server-ip`.

The good news is then that it seems to be reaching my Phoenix app, so thank you! Hopefully I'll figure out this next bug.